# question about proof with Rules of Inference

Tags: logic

After lots of thinking, I couldn't figure out how to do the proof, tried to split to cases when C is true and the rest is false, then when B is true and the rest is false and so on, but it feels like the wrong way.

Using the following list of rules, I have to proof **A$\to$D** using the premises: $\begin{cases}
A\to(B\lor C) \\[2ex]
B\to(C\lor D) \\[2ex]
C\to D
\end{cases}$

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $C\to D$ as a premise, and $D\to D$ from rule $11$, which by rule $13$ give us $(C \lor D) \to D$. Now use rule $10$ on that statement together with premise $2$ to derive $B \to D$.

We now have $B \to D$ and $C\to D$, which gives us $(B\lor C) \to D$ by rule $13$. A final application of rule $10$ with that statement and premise $1$ is enough to get $A \to D$.

Comment: you're genius! thanks

Comment: global question - is it legal (in such proofs) to split to cases as I thought in the beginning?

Comment: @Ami Not really in a proof like this. If you are specifically to use the rules of inference, then you're not really allowed to interpret the symbols as "or", "not", "implies" and so on at all. In such a basic setting, the symbols have no meaning at all, other than exactly what the inference rules tell you. You may only use the rules exactly as they stand. Of course, if in a normal proof in some other fields of mathematics you come over this exact setup of premises, you're more than allowed to do so. I would also consider using rule $9$ (contraposition) frequently. At least I do.